# What is the racing board game they are playing in Netflix's show about Formula 1, s02e09?

Tags: identify-this-game, formula-one

They play some kind of board game with joysticks, she says "that's all we did growing up" so it's quite old and probably not very computerised.

Now, from what I gather the cars turn automatically, and they have to handle braking at the correct moments? I have no clue. Looks fascinating. I don't have enough vocabulary for google to give me anything sensible. Have anyone any idea which game is this?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like [Slot Car racing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slot_car_racing).  There are a number of different brands, so which set is hard to identify, but here's an example by Tyco:

[image: Tyco slot car racing]

Comment: Just some additional info:
If this is in germany it is most certainly from carrera, as these games are referred to as "carrera tracks". 
At least in germany pretty much every kid had one of those since the 80s or so.

Comment: @bibleblade Since the 70s ;-).

Comment: You might also explicitly clarify that slot car racing wouldn't be considered a "board game".

Answer (score 13):

This is [Scalextric](https://uk.scalextric.com/) or a clone.